# How optimised is this Cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

[Edit] I'm using Neo4j 4.2.1

I have this need for a Cypher query that brings back a complete tree given its root node. All nodes and relationships must be fetched and present only once in the returned sets. Here's what I have come to:

```
MATCH p = (n)-[*..]->(m)
WHERE id(n) = 0
WITH relationships(p) AS r
WITH distinct last(r) as rel
WITH [node IN [startNode(rel), endNode(rel)] | node] AS tmp, rel
UNWIND tmp AS node
RETURN collect(DISTINCT node) AS nodes, collect(distinct rel) AS relationships;
```

Running the query on our database to get about 820 nodes makes the thing crash for lack of memory (5Gb allowed). Hard to believe. So I'm wondering : Is this query ill-born? Is there one technique I'm using that shouldn't be used for my purpose?

Comment: Is there a node property guaranteed to be the same on all nodes in a contiguous tree? Also, are you sure you need to return all the nodes and all the relationships? Usually, you return specific data pieces, which is often faster.

Comment: There is no "tagging" property to filter the nodes that belong to the tree, if this is your question's meaning. The goal is to blindly dump the whole tree and have all the properties for each node and relationship so that the tree can be re-imported "as-is" in another database. It works pretty fine, but the memory overhead may become an issue in time. Also, execution time really is not an issue here.

Comment: If you just want to copy the database, go into neo4j/data, and copy the /databases/neo4j and /transactions/neo4j folders.

Comment: My goal is not to copy the whole database. That's the point. The data I'm concerned about is organised as a collection of "small", independent trees. Why I want to do is to pick a tree, one at a time, by its root's id.

Comment: All right, well take my answer and modify the `WHERE` clause to get just the parents you want (just do length 1 paths). Store all the data you need to re-construct the nodes; you might also need some additional info to get relationships. Put all this stuff into tab-separated value files, then use the CSV importing ability to put the data into a new database.

Comment: Variable-length paths are the reason your query is taking so long. You could probably speed it up considerably, and take a lot less RAM, if you know you have an upper-bound on the path length, and incorporate that into your query.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I appreciate every single bit of knowledge I can grab. That being said, as I wrote in my original post, my first issue is not about execution time, it's about memory usage. This is the aspect I want to address first.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you come up with a node property that is guaranteed to be the same on all the nodes in a contiguous tree, if you don't have one already. I'll call that property `same_prop`. Here's what I do to run queries like the one you're running:

1. Index `same_prop`. If you have different node labels, then you need this index created for each different node label you expect to have in the tree.
   `CREATE INDEX samepropnode FOR (n:your_label) ON (n.same_prop)`
   is the kind of thing you need in Neo4j 4+. In Neo4j, indices are cheap, and can sometimes speed up queries quite a bit.
2. Collect all possible values of `same_prop` and store them in a text file (I use tab-separated values as safer than comma-separated values).
3. Use the Python driver, or your language of choice that has a Neo4j driver written (strongly recommend Neo4j-provided drivers, not third-party) to write wrapper code that executes a Cypher query something like this:

```
MATCH (p)-->(c)
USING INDEX p:your_label(same_prop)
WHERE p.same_prop IN [ same_prop_list ]
RETURN DISTINCT
    p.datapiece1 AS `first_parent_datapiece`,
    p.datapiecen AS `nth_parent_datapiece`,
    c.datapiece1 AS `first_child_datapiece`,
    c.datapiecen AS `nth_child_datapiece`
```

It's not a good idea, in general, to return nodes and relationships unless you're debugging.

Then in your Python (for example) code, you're simply going to read in all your `same_prop` values from the file you got in Step 2, chunk up the values in reasonable size chunks, maybe 1,000 or 10,000, and substitute them in for the `[ same_prop_list ]` in the Cypher query on-the-fly.

Comment: "It's not a good idea, in general, to return nodes and relationships unless you're debugging." Although I tend to agree, I'd say, with all due respect, that it is always a good idea to use the right means to achieve your goals. I my case, transplanting a complete data tree in a new database garden is what I want.